# Checkstyle check RegexpHeader: Does not allow me to assign a regex to the value of its property header

Tags: java, regex, checkstyle

I a using `RegexpHeader` check from `Checkstyle`. I have a property header whose value I have set to

```
^(.|\n)*@.*ParamsAreNonNull$ .
```

The checkstyle throws an error:

```
cannot initialize module RegexpHeader - Cannot set property 'header' to '^(.|\n)*@.*ParamsAreNonNull$' in module RegexpHeader'
```

What could be the reason? This regex works perfectly on regex101.com and is the one that I want.

I changed the check to Regexp since the above check is only for single line apparently.

```
<module name="Regexp">
            <property name="format" value="^(.|\n)*@.*ParamsAreNonNull$"/>
            <property name="message" value="Annotation Not Found"/>
            <property name="ignoreComments" value="true"/>
            <property name="severity" value="error"/>
</module>
```

Error:

```
java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4568)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3777)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4604)
```

Comment: Can you add the exact line of code or configuration you're using to set the header? It would help to figure out the problem.

Comment: Since this is essentially a debugging question, we will need you to provide a minimal working example code-sample that can be copied and executed (or at least attempted :) )